# Event bubbling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-bubbling

There is something I can't seem to understand about the definition of bubbling.

I know that event bubbling means event propagation from inner element to outer element. I also know that you can "choose" you way of propagation with the last optional parameter of addEventListener().

The thing I do not understand is this one:

```
<body>
    <div id = "divi">
        <p id = "para">Paragraph</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var elementd = document.getElementById('divi');

        elementd.addEventListener("click", MessageD);

        function MessageD(){
            alert('A message');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Here I attach a click event to my div element. By default, the click event is bubbling, which means he is going up through the DOM. But when I click on my paragraph, the click event is executed.

To my understanding, that means that the click event propagates to the "p" child element first, or DOWN the DOM. Can someone explain to me why and what happens? Thanks!

--- EDIT AFTER SOME ANSWERS ---

Maybe what troubles me is better explained through this example:

```
<body>
    <style>
        #myDiv, #results {
            margin: 50px;
        }

        #myDiv {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #000;
        }

        #myDiv div {
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #555;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="myDiv">
        <div>Text 1</div>
        <div>Text 2</div>
        <div>Text 3</div>
        <div>Text 4</div>
    </div>

    <div id="results"></div>

    <script>
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
        results = document.getElementById('results');

        myDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            results.innerHTML += "I'm in.<br />";
        }, false);

        myDiv.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            results.innerHTML += "I'm out.<br />";
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

If you try running this code, you'll be "out" and "in" any time you enter and exit a child div... meaning you'll be "in" in child divs.

Doesn't that means that the events propagate from the parent to the child, or down way?

--- FINAL EDIT ---
I finally understood: I made a confusion between an event and an event handler.

An event is just a click, so anything in a page can receive it. Once you have clicked, this click event is going to go to the top of the DOM, and when it encounters click event handler, the function associated to the event handler will be executed.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Surely you said it yourself, event propagation from inner element to outer element. The p hits, nothing handles it so it by default bubbles up to div

Comment: Bubble: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link3 .    Capture: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link2

Comment: As far as I know the `p` element actually is responsible for executing the function. There’s also the event target that you can check. You can even bind a `change` event listener to a `div` containing lots of `input` elements which will fire if _one_ of the children changes.

Comment: What I do not understand is that, to me, the event is attached to the div. Then it should go up from the div to the let's say body. But the p should never handle or be able to execute the event. I can't understand that

Comment: But the p does handle the event, hat makes you think it doesn't? It's acting in default therefore it will continue the propagation as you said in your own words. https://jsfiddle.net/ut2r5yrt/

Comment: It's because my event is attached to my div. So if the event propagate from the p to my div when it is executed, that means that p "knows" my event. But how can it knows it since I told it nothing about the event? To me, that means that div told to p that it has a click event. To my understanding, p should know nothing about the click event, and then nothing should happen when I click on my p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To my understanding, that means that the click event propagates to the "p" child element first, or DOWN the DOM.

No. In that case the `p` element is the target of event. Event propagates to the `div` element. `div` element has a `click` handler and it's executed.

This is how events work. Target of the event is an element that has triggered the event, the target can be the element that you have attached the listener to or one of it's children/descendants. `target` property of the `event` object refers to the target element of the event and when `addEventListener` is used for attaching an event listener, `this` value of the handler refers to the owner of the handler, in this case the `div` element.

The fact that you have attached an event listener has nothing to do with how event works. Click events are fired whenever the user clicks. It's you, the developer, that attaches an event listener for listening to specific event triggered for an element. If you don't attach a listener, still the event is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how it is that the p element is the target of the event. Shouldn't it be the div itself as I attached the event to the div? How can a child element "start the execution" of its parent event when the way of propagation of the event is down to up. I don't know if I'm totally clear but that is what is bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the paragraph, it's not being handled there, so it propagates up to the DIV. If you use this version of the code, it shows which element the event is being handled by. The alert says `divi`, not `para`.

```js
var elementd = document.getElementById('divi');

elementd.addEventListener("click", MessageD);

function MessageD() {
  alert(this.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="divi">
  <p id="para">Paragraph</p>
</div>
```